# read hive metadata options

Tags: hadoop, hive, hcatalog

I am new to hive. I want to capture the list of tables and associated metadata (like columns, no. of rows etc) in all the databases. What am I looking for is some kind of a script that I can hand it over and anyone can run it and provide me with the output by writing it to a file.

One approach is to write a mapreduce program that will connect to hive and pull this information.

Other approach is to somehow loop through the list of tables and get this information. I am aware of `show tables` and `describe table` commands, but not sure how to use these commands in a script and how can this script be run.

Which approach should I take? What other options/approaches are available to perform this task? Thanks for any help.
[For an RDBMS I could do this by just writing a SQL query on the system catalog tables.]

Answer (score 0):

I would use Spark, mapreduce, or [HPL/SQL](http://www.hplsql.org/doc) to loop through the list of tables (as you mentioned) and then grab the needed data using various show statements. I would first look into the HPL/SQL approach so it can be run as any Hive query, then I would attempt it with Spark if the first approach didn't work out.

```
-- loop on the values displayed in show tables
show tables;
-- then execute tblproperties and describe to get the metadata you are after
show tblproperties yourTableName;
describe yourTableName;
```

Comment: How do I loop through the output from `show tables`? Where do I run this  script?

Comment: This is just psuedo code logic for what you would need program, kind of just a hive level starting point for you. I would look into doing HPL/SQL which you would execute in Hive.

Answer (score 0):

using hive metastore APIs is one possible solution. Refer [HiveMetaStore APIs](https://hive.apache.org/javadocs/r0.13.1/api/metastore/org/apache/hadoop/hive/metastore/HiveMetaStoreClient.html)

You can also look at WebHcat APIs[Hcat for Hive](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/WebHCat+Reference+Hive)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will need to configure the hive metastore to use MYSQL or oracle,then you can query the SYS tables in mysql or oracle database and get what you want.By default hive uses Derby database

See 
https://dzone.com/articles/how-configure-mysql-metastore

Hope this helps